# Upload Photos using Silverlight - Ria Services

Tags: web-services, silverlight-4.0, ria

i'm trying to find a good exemple on uploading and downloading images using solely Silverlgith + Ria Services, i tried to find some but i failed, please any help would be appreciated.

thank you all in advance

Comment: Why not just store files on disk instead of sql server by  just pointing filename from sql server to the physical file ?

Answer (score 1):

I just found some useful walk trough [here](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Storing-images-in-SQL-Server-with-RIA-Services.aspx) and make sure to read [follow-up](http://www.pitorque.de/MisterGoodcat/post/Improving-the-image-upload-sample.aspx) that improves the save process and used image

Answer (score 1):

We did it by saving the images on disk (not in a DB) - like this:

Upload image:

- Write a Domain Service with an operation like `void UploadJPGImage(string uniqueName, byte[] jpgBytes)`. This needs to be marked with the attribute for ClientAccess. The (server-side) implementation saves the image on the disk.
- for the uniqueName, we generate a GUID client-side

Download image:

- HTTP Handler - write an HTTP handler for downloading the image using a URL containing the unique name parameter passed by the client when uploading the image
- Or, one could write a Domain Service operation, like `byte[] DownloadJPGImage(string uniqueName`)